# Given a list with n elements, need to use a heap somehow to find always the biggest k elements after insetions and deletions in O(K)?

Tags: algorithm

Given a list with n elements,and given K and the value of the Kth element in the list. required to build a heap in 0(n) from the list, any other insertion to heap in O(log n) (adding another elements not from the list) ,delete in O(n), 
how to find the biggest k element no matter what changed in the heap in O(k)?
for example: given list (2,4,6,10,9,12) and given k=3 and value=9,
the k biggest are 10,9,12. after that if deleted 10 and 12 ,the k bigggest will be 4,6,9 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain:

1. 'Big' max heap, of size (n-k)
2. 'Small' min heap, of size k.

At any time point the largest-k numbers are in the smaller heap. the root of the big heap is the candidate to be inserted to the smaller heap.

Once a number is inserted:

- If it is bigger than the root of the small heap, then it should be among the
  largest-k. pop the root of the small heap, and insert the new number to the small heap.
- If it is smaller than the root of K2 - insert it to the big heap.

Once a number is deleted:

- If it is smaller than the root of the small heap, then this number exists in the big heap only. find it (in the big heap) and delete it.
- if it is bigger than the root of the smaller heap - then this number is among the largest-k. Find it in the small heap, delete it, and pop the root of the big heap - and insert it to the small heap.

This algorithm uses the complexity bounds you mentioned.

Comment: thank you, very helpful! one more thing: in addition to all of that given a stack that save all the inserted item in the order that happend, how to use in the stack for delete each item from the heaps in O(log n)?